# foreach вывести массив, все кроме

Tags: php, массивы

Как вывести массив **$arr** все кроме **2**

```
$var = "2";
$arr = array("1"=>"1",
"2"=>"2",
"3"=>"3");
```

**ожидаемый резултат:**

```
1
3
```

Comment: Имеете ввиду значение или ключ массива?

Comment: допустим что бы по ключу выводились

Comment: взгляните на мой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант

```
unset($arr[$var]);
```

если с поиском

```
$key = array_search($var, $arr);
if ($key !== false)
{
    unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо это то что нужно)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем удалять ключи, если можно просто исключать их)

Comment: использовать цикл плохая практика. Если необходимо иметь исходный массив, Вы всегда моете работать с его копией

Answer (score 0):

Если исключаете ключ массива:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    if ($key != 2) {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Если исключаете значение элемента массива:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    if ($item != 2) {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: итак сойдет, хотя первый вариант тож хорош

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой альтернативный вариант, для того чтобы сделать ровно то, что было озвучено в вопросе: вывести значения элементов массива, кроме элемента с произвольным ключом. Мы же не знаем, может ТСу потом исходный массив понадобится, зачем  тогда удалять элементы? :) Ключи заменил буквенными, для наглядности.

```
$sourceArray = ["a" => "1",
                "b" => "2",
                "c" => "3"];  // Короткий синтаксис доступен с 5.4 
$ignoreKey = "b";

$filterFunc = function($key) 
              use ($ignoreKey) {  // Кроме ключа, в функции нам поднабится
                                  // внешняя переменная
                  return $key != $ignoreKey;  // Когда равняется True, 
                                              // элемент массива "проходит"
              };
foreach (array_filter(
            $sourceArray,         // Исходный массив
            $filterFunc,          // Наша фильтрующая функция
            ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY  // Фильтрация функцией происходит по ключу
            ) as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "\n";
}
```